# Loading new images into UIImageView, memory from previous images is not released

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, instruments

My app has a view with three `UIImageViews`.  There are about 150 images as resource files, each a .jpg of about 24k.  The app will show all of the images, but only three at a time.

But every time I click the button to load three more images into the `UIImageViews`, the "Overall Bytes" column in Instruments increases by about 700K, until I eventually get a low memory warning and then the app crashes.  Somehow, the memory I use for each load of three images isn't being released.

I've googled around and tried every way I know to do this, but no success and I need help.

I've tried this: (This code is part of the action to load three more images.  The three ImageViews are `imgShownLeft`, `imgShownMiddle`, and `imgShownRight`.  Those are instance variables. I first have to put `currentImage` in all three `UIImageViews`, and then put `previousImage` in the left one and `nextImage` in the right one:

```
NSString *strImageToSet = [[imgNamesArray objectAtIndex:currentImage] stringByAppendingFormat:@".jpg"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:strImageToSet];
[imgShownMiddle setImage:img];
[imgShownLeft setImage:img];
[imgShownRight setImage:img];

NSString *strPreviousImage = [[imgNamesArray objectAtIndex:previousImage] stringByAppendingFormat:@".jpg"];
img = [UIImage imageNamed:strPreviousImage];
[imgShownLeft setImage:img];

NSString *strNextImage = [[imgNamesArray objectAtIndex:nextImage] stringByAppendingFormat:@".jpg"];
img = [UIImage imageNamed:strNextImage];
[imgShownRight setImage:img];
```

Then I tried this:
    instead of:

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:strImageToSet];
```

I used:

```
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strImageToSet];
```

and assigned `img` to the `UIImageViews` the same way, followed by
        `[img release];`

Then I tried:

```
    UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strImageToSet] autorelease];
```

Then I tried:

```
    img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[imgNamesArray objectAtIndex:currentImage] ofType:@"jpg"]];
```

But in every case the memory requirements grew with each run of this action.

I know it's possible to keep three images loaded at a time without holding 150 images in memory!  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any insight.
/SD

Comment: did u find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is to use

```
img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[imgNamesArray objectAtIndex:currentImage] ofType:@"jpg"]];
```

to do your loading (because `UIImage imageNamed:` supposedly does some caching you don't want), and then add

```
[img release];
```

after each `setImage` call, because the subviews should be `retain`-ing the images, so you're leaking a reference count.

I would have thought that the second version with `autorelease` would have worked properly, but to be honest Cocoa memory management rules still manage to confuse me even when I'm pretty sure I know what I'm doing.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `release` on those images, you don't own them.